# Ubuntu: How do I tell if my USB ports are v1.1 or v2.0?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I just noticed that when I disconnected a USB drive, a message was logged from `usb 1-1:`.

Does this mean my ports are USB v1.1, this particular device is a USB v1.1 device, or something else?

Under Ubuntu Linux, is there a way to tell what version of USB a port on my computer is using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `1-1` is just the number Linux gave to your device. It means, as far as I can tell, the device on the first port on the first USB bus (take a look at `lsusb` to see if bus 001 is a 1.1 or 2.0 bus). On my machine, I see 1-2.1 and 1-2.2 (the keyboard and mouse plugged on both ports of the hub plugged on the second port of the first USB bus). Note that the *same* port is often on *two* buses, one 1.1 (OHCI or UHCI) and one 2.0 (EHCI), and which one is used depends on whether the device is high-speed (2.0 only) or full-speed/low-speed (1.1 or 2.0).

You can see more interesting information with `lsusb -v` or `sudo lsusb -v`.

Answer (score 12):

```
lsusb -v
```

Look for value for bcdUSB field. Should be either 2.00 or 1.10.

Comment: Thank you for pointing bcdUSB field, you saved my day :)