# How to tell if my USB ports are 1.1 or 2.0 for different OSes?

Tags: usb

In the same vein as this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/14076/ubuntu-how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0), how do you determine what speed the USB ports are on your machine with different OSes installed?

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7
- Mac OS X
- Linux ([Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/14076/ubuntu-how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0))
- etc.

Comment: my problem always seems to be identifying which ports on the case connect with which ones...

Comment: Check out hyperslug's answer below for a suggestion on how to determine that.

Answer (score 5):

The way I check for Windows is *Start → Run → `devmgmt.msc` → Universal Serial Bus controllers -> (expand)*.

- If there's one that says "Enhanced Host Controller" then it has 2.0.
- If they're all "Universal Host Controller" assume 1.1.

At least that's how it looks in Windows Vista, Server 2008 and XP for me. Windows 2000 Pro says something like USB 2.0 root.

Comment: An easier way on Windows XP and above if you have a mixture of USB 1.1 and 2.0 ports is to just plug in a USB 2.0 compliant device. If the port is USB 1.1, Windows will notify you that moving to a faster port will improve performance. If you don't receive a notification, its safe to assume the port is USB 2.0 compliant.

Comment: Interesting that my current computer shows a mixture: http://img32.imageshack.us/i/usblistcapture728200962.png/  I'll have to use Kenneth's suggestion to see which is which.

Comment: I have heard somewhere that there can be both 1.1 and 2.0 controllers in a single chip, selecting the right one automatically. Dunno if that makes any sense though.

Comment: @Kenneth, that just turns the question into "how do I know if [some device] is USB 2.0-compliant?"  Good tip though.

Comment: This tip does not work very well in Windows 7; I know my board has 10 USB 2.0 ports and 2 USB 3.0 ports, and they are labelled 5*Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller and 2*Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller.

Comment: BTW, on Device Manager, the "View" / "Devices by Connection" is immensely more useful for tracking like this than the "Devices by Type", because then you can see the connection path for every device. Like, "Keyboard connects to USB hub X, which connects to hub Y".

Answer (score 5):

On Linux

- USB 2.0 will use the `ehci_hcd` module
- USB 1.x will use either `ohci_hcd` or `uhci_hcd` modules.

You can find out which module is being used by `lspci -v` or `lshw`.

Perhaps a better method (if you're interested in particular ports/devices) is to use 
"lsusb -t"

Answer (score 2):

On OSX, you can go launch *System Profiler* and look for USB. If you have a High-Speed bus, that means USB 2.0.

[image]

Also, the speed is shown, here it's 480 Mb/sec, indicating USB 2.0

[image]

Also this may help:

```
$ ioreg -k IOUserClientClass | grep UserClientClass | grep USBDeviceUserClient | head -1 | sed -e 's/.* = //'
"IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X it depends on the hardware, not the software.  If you are running a fairly modern Mac, then you have USB 2.0.  All Intel Macs and the last couple of generations of PowerPC machines have USB 2.0.  I had a first generation aluminum PowerBook 17" that I bought 5.5 years ago.  That machine had USB 2.0, so unless you get a really old machine it will probably have USB 2.0.

Comment: On Windows, it also depends on the hardware :)