# How fast is the transfer going?

Tags: usb, file-transfer, flip

I have a flip mino video camera (the non HD one).  I think the file transfer between it and my laptop is going quite slowly (400 mb in 2 minutes or so).

How can I find out whether the USB connection is going over USB 2 or USB 1.1?
Btw, I've tried multiple computers (both mac and pc).

It used to go a lot faster.

Comment: Sad part about these devices: on-board memory that cannot be unplugged and interfaced over an adapter/card-reader.

Answer (score 1):

it is definitely faster than USB 1.1 where a 400 MB file would take around 15 minutes to transfer but it's also far from USB 2.0 maximum transfer speed (around 20 seconds for 400 MB).

this could be related to the slow read speed of the storage media.

Answer (score 0):

That transfer rate is slow even for 1.1. But there isn't anything wrong with your Mino. It supports 2.0 and, I'm assuming, your computer too.

The problem is instead the fact flash drives like those in these type of devices are notoriously slow. I don't have any specifics on the Mino transfer rates. But this is nothing too surprising. In fact I'd expect such a transfer rate were I to buy such a device.

Comment: 200MB/min is faster than USB1.1; 1.1 gets 12Mbit/s = 1.5MB/s = 90MB/min.  looks like this transfer is a bit over 2x USB1.1 speed, at 3.3MB/s = 26.7Mbit/s.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to tell if my USB ports are 1.1 or 2.0 for different OSes?](https://superuser.com/questions/14107/how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0-for-different-oses) for ways to tell if your ports are 1.1 or 2.0.  Most likely the memory in the Mino is slow at reads.  Perhaps someone else will post their speeds for comparison.