# How can I find out which USB port is 1.0 or 2.0 on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, usb, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if my USB ports are 1.1 or 2.0 for different OSes?](https://superuser.com/questions/14107/how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0-for-different-oses)

My laptop has 4 USB ports. I want to know which port is 1.0, which port is 2.0 and so on.

For example, are all ports are of different type? If so, how can I identity which port is of what type?

Comment: Disagree, this has an addition part of "if I have 4, how do I know which is which"

Comment: Well, you already answered that -- it won't be lost or deleted anyway @soandos

Comment: Still a valid question though, and so should not be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to tell what type each port is look at [How to tell if my usb ports are 1.1 or 2.0 for different OSes](https://superuser.com/questions/14107/how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0-for-different-oses). To figure out which port is which plug in a device, and see where it shows up.